# addition and subtraction problems in c++

Tags: visual-c++

If after addition, you have to divide by the third number, you need more than 3 variables. Why is that?
can anyone please help me with this problem. it will be very grateful.why do we need to after addition, you have to divide by the third number, you need more than 3 variables. Why is that?
thank you

```
#include <stdio.h> 
class res 
{ 
   int a[6],i; 
   public: 
   int result() 
   {
      for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
      { 
         if(a[i]%3==0) 
         {
            "sum=sum+a[i]";
         }
      }
   } 
};  // Added newly

int main() 
{
    res r; 
    int i,a[5];
    cout<<"enter three numbers"; 
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
       cin>>a[i]);
    } 
    r.result(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Post the code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: #include <stdio.h> 
class res
{
int a[6],i;
public:
 int result()
{for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
 if(a[i]%3==0)
 {"sum=sum+a[i]"; }
 }
int main()
{
res r;
int i,a[5];

cout<<"enter three numbers";
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 cin>>a[i]);
}
 
r.result();
return 0;
}

Comment: i just want is the reason after addition of 3no  you have to divide by the third number, you need more than 3 variables. Why is that?

Comment: You can edit your original post to include that code, it will be so much more readable.

Comment: Well, the first sentence is not true: you don't need more than 3 variables. In fact, you need no variables. Why not show us the statement that contains that error? Or show us the code you are trying? Thanks!

Comment: well addition of 3no and then the 3 no has to be divided with the sum of 3 no so why more then 3 variables are used

Comment: What three variables are you talking about? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand that the array variable in `main` is different from the class member `a`. And in `result` method, class variable `a` is not initialized with valid values to do a `%` operation on it.

```
if(a[i]%3==0) 
{
    "sum=sum+a[i]"; // And probably here you meant sum=sum+a[i];
                    // string should be enclosed in double quotes.
}
```

With the above modification made, class `res` doesn't know what the variable `sum` is.

---

Given the number of many other mistakes in your program, I suggest you to read a book from the [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).